# Seleccionar datos de una tabla relacionada con un usuario

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Tengo estas dos tablas:

```
users:
+-----+----------+------------+
| id  |  nombre  |  apellidos |
+-----+----------+------------+
|   1 | juan     | apellido1  |
|   2 | pepito   | apeliido2  |
+-----+----------+------------+

subjects:
+----+--------------+----------+---------+
| id |  asignatura  | profesor | user_id |
+----+--------------+----------+---------+
|  1 | literatura   | ana      |       1 |
|  2 | historia     | alberto  |       1 |
|  3 | matemáticas  | esther   |       2 |
|  4 | inglés       | sergio   |       2 |
+----+--------------+----------+---------+
```

**Pues lo que pretendo es que PHP me devuelva en el caso de juan => literatura e historia y en el caso de pepito => matemáticas e inglés**.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto:

```
<?php

session_start();

require('gdb.php');

$user_id = $_SESSION["userid"];

$data = $conn->prepare('
        SELECT subjects.subject_name
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN subjects ON :userid = subjects.user_id
');

$data->execute(array(':userid' => $user_id));

$result = $data->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

El archivo gdb.php simplemente contiene los datos de la conexión con la base de datos.

**Pues bien, usando ese código me devuelve de más de valores repetidos.**

**El enlace que tengo entre mis tablas es el siguiente:**

```
+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| subjects   | user_id     | subjects_ibfk_1 | users                 | id                     |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

Gracias por cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que tienes que utilizar en tu consulta es un `JOIN`

Quedaría algo así:

```
$data = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM subjects AS SU 
INNER JOIN users AS US ON US.id = SU.user_id
WHERE US.id = :id');

$data->execute(array(':id' => $user_id));
```

Creo que donde te estaba fallando es al hacer el join.

Comment: A qué te refieres con AS y SU?

Comment: La sentencia AS es para asignar un ALIAS a la tabla subjects y users en mi caso les decidi poner SU y US respectivamente, tu puedes ponerle como mejor te agrade, te recomiendo usar ALIAS para hacer referencia a campos de tablas diferentes.

Comment: Te agradecería si no es molestia que me pusieras un ejemplo con mis tablas, gracias.

Comment: Es simplemente por aclararme un poco, es que me estoy liando un poco con esto ya que acabo de empezar con las relación entre tablas. :(

Comment: Lo siento, he editado mi respuesta, no me había percatado de que utilizas sentencias preparadas, de esa manera de debería de funcionar. Te dejo un link por si aún tienes dudas con la sentencias AS de SQL https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: ¿Por qué pones SU y US?

Comment: Son ALIAS digamos que para no escribir subjects.user_id y users.id simplemente a las tablas subjects y users les pongo un nombre(alias) para acortarlo y hacer referencia a esas tablas. 

SU = Tabla subjects
US = Tabla users

Comment: ahh, vale gracias :) voy a probar

Comment: gracias, funciona perfectamente.